# Question on next prime function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The function $P(n)$ gives the smallest prime larger or equal to n. Example: $P(3)=3,P(4)=5.$

Show that: equation $P(x)^2-P(x^2)\equiv 4\pmod6$ have only one solution as $x=3$?

Source code Pari GP

```
for(x=1,100000,if((nextprime(x)^2-nextprime(x^2))%6==4,print([x])))
[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>3$, $P(x)$ can only have the form $6k+1$,$6h+5$ or
$$P(x) \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6\iff (P(x))^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
From the equation, we can deduce  that
$$1-P(x^2)\equiv 4 \pmod 6 \iff P(x^2)\equiv 3 \pmod 6 $$
Hence, $P(x^2)$ is divisible by 3 $\implies$ contradiction.

So, $x \le 3$ and the sole solution is $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with the small cases we can assume that $x \geq 3$.
Observe that the equation reduces to, $$P(x)^2-P(x^2) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$ and $$P(x)^2-P(x^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$
now the former one is obvious as we are assuming $x \geq 3$. (just note that prime number larger than $2$ is always odd).

Now we solve the equation,
$$P(x)^2-P(x^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

Recall that a square number is always congruent to either $1$ or $2$ modulo $3$.
\

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $P(x)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
In this case, as $P(x)$ is a prime number divisibe by $3$. We observe that $P(x)= 3 \implies x = 2 \text{ or } 3 $.

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $P(x)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ 
In this case $P(x)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies P(x^2) \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $
Now as in last case, we observe that $P(x^2) = 3$. But this is impossible.

Thus we conclude that the given equation has only two solutions. Namely, $x=2 \text{ and } x=3$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant all squares are congruent to 0 or 1 mod 3.